# Significado de "sicofantia"

Tags: definiciones, significado, palabras-raras

El [**optotipo para la sicofantia**](http://www.centrospalomar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=249%3Aoptotipo-sicofantia-palomar-para-el-diagnostico-de-la-sicofantia) parece estar diseñado para detectar a **simuladores**. Sin embargo, no encuentro esa palabra en los diccionarios, por lo que me planteo si es correcta la interpretación "**sicofante = simulador**" y si está extendida esa acepción.

Las palabras más parecidas y aparentemente relacionadas (sicofanta, sicofante) que he encontrado tienen significados diferentes:

En el DRAE [**sicofante**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xnnbqj6) remite a [**sicofanta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xnks3lS), que figura escuetamente como

> Del lat. sycophanta, y este del gr. συκοφάντης sykophántēs.
>   1. m. Impostor, calumniador.

En otro [**diccionario**](http://es.dictionarist.com/sicofante) se recogen otras definiciones de sicofante:

> 1. Persona que intenta ganar el favor de otra comportándose de forma zalamera y servil
> 2. Delator o informante de la policía u otra autoridad

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicofanta) recoge que

> "En la Antigua Atenas un sicofante o sicofanta (en griego συκοφάντης *sykophantes*) era un denunciante profesional. [...] Por extensión, el término sicofante/a designa a un individuo bajo y despreciable, que busca obtener una posición o estatus personal mediante adulación hacia otras personas que comúnmente disponen ya de ciertas influencias y estatus social o tribal.

La [Enciclopedia Universal Ilustrada Europeo-Americana](http://www.filosofia.org/enc/eui/e551144.htm) añade información adicional, pero no nuevas acepciones.

Comment: Entiendo que si un "sicofante" es un impostor o calumniador, la "sicofantia" es la calumnia, el hecho realizado, por lo que entiendo el término podría ser correcto aunque no venga recogido en el DRAE. En todo caso, también podríamos preguntar qué es un "optotipo", que tampoco viene en el DRAE.

Comment: He supuesto el significado de "simulador" por el texto con el que comienza el texto en cuestión: "La simulación de una ambliopía unilateral podemos descubrirla fácilmente con las pruebas de visión binocular. Pero cuando el paciente simula una ambliopía bilateral es mas difícil de detectarla.
En la literatura podemos encontrar ... el empleo de los Optotipos de Thibaudet, que son unos optotipos ... en los que la agudeza visual se mide ..."  Wikipedia recoge que un optotipo "es un instrumento oftalmológico utilizado para evaluar la agudeza visual y la visión de los colores."

Comment: *Optotipo* es una palabra técnica, por eso no sale en el DRAE. Y *sicofantia* parece un derivado bien formado de *sicofante*, con el significado que se podría esperar, así que no veo problemas con el nombre del aparato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo diría que la interpretación es correcta con matices, y con la definición del DRAE tenemos suficiente para explicarlo. Lo que detecta el *optotipo* no son simuladores, sino [impostores](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L5zStQe), que es lo que es un *sicofante*. Es decir, detecta gente "que finge o engaña con apariencia de verdad". En el caso que nos concierne, se detectan impostores que fingen sufrir de ambliopía bilateral. Lo que pasa es que en medicina es un poco delicado usar según qué palabras (no queda bien que tildes a un paciente de impostor), por lo que se dice que las personas simulan patologías. De hecho, en muchas ocasiones seguramente ni siquiera serán conscientes de ello.

El término sicofante no lo conocía, pero me parece adecuado para describir a estas personas ya que suena muy culto y rimbombante. De este sustantivo se deriva *sicofantia*, usando el sufijo -ia:

> **[-ia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KrTqAy7)**
>
> Del lat. *-ia*.
>
> 1. suf. Aparece en sustantivos femeninos, generalmente abstractos, en su mayoría heredados del latín. *Vigilia, eficacia, ignominia.*

Así, aunque no aparezca en el diccionario podemos saber cómo está formada la palabra y a qué se refiere.

Por cierto, un *optotipo* es la típica tabla con letras o símbolos que se usa para medir la visión de alguien. En inglés recibe el nombre más descriptivo de *[eye chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_chart)*.